# Receiver class doesn't recognize ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I want to play a sound as a notification when battery charge is full.

in my receiver class I wrote 2 more notifications for "power connected" and "power disconnected" and they works ok!

but my receiver doesn't recognize the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. I've searched a lot and I found out that I must register it programmatically.

The problem is that I need to register it without any Activity. Because I want to notify "Battery_Fully_charged" even when my program doesn't run.

how can I register something like this within my receiver ("MyReceiver.class")?

here is the sample code that I found and it workes. But I want to do it without an Activity.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

Edit:
what is the difference between Service and Broadcase Receiver? I tried the Service but still didn't get any result

Comment: Use a service instead of an activity. Note: Android is getting rid of implicit intents like this so it might not work in Android N.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Of course I used Service and still it doesn't work. Can you post some example?

Comment: There's no such thing as "of course" here, how am I supposed to know? What if you posted what you have tried, so we don't repeat ourselves?

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec sorry. I just tried Service, there is nothing else. really sorry:(
if I use Service, I must Start it right? and what can i do if the service stop from memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED):

> You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()`. [...]

This means:

1) Only a `BroadcastReceiver` can receive these intents.

2) Only a dynamically registered receiver can receive these intents.

You already understand how to do it inside an activity let's look at the service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IntentFilter batteryIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    private final BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            // React.
        }
    };

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, batteryIntentFilter);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

You can decrease the chance of the service getting killed by putting it to foreground (google "foreground service").

As mentioned in http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#bg-opt some implicit intents are going away so be prepared `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is going to be among them.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I used this class, and I've added the <service> tag in Manifest file. but I'm still unable to get this action. Doesn't this Service need to start from somewhere? The "OnCreate" runs automatically?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you need to call `startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));` at some point. If you need it to run all the time you could subclass `Application`. See http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Just one more question. Does this service stops in some conditions? I just removed the unregisterReceiver to keep recognizing the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. except that, working the service is not matter in my app. Does this work this way?[I used Application to start it]

Comment: Removing that has no effect except the system shouting that you didnt unregister your receiver before the service got destroyed. And memory leaks. Better put it back. You can kill the service manually by calling `stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));`.